# Limit number of characters in Label

Tags: c#, winforms, string, text, label

I am using label in my winform . It displays the value which I enter in another textbox. My problem is label does not display whole characters I enter in textbox. Label's size is width=160 and height=19. So it truncates the last value. For testing purpose when I enter "W" in caps in textbox ;label can display maximum 13 "W"s. So I am trimming the
charater's by using labelname.substring(0,10); and for next three characters I am appending 3 dots(...)
   But this solution is not desirable to my senior. He is telling me that if I enter all small letters "l" in textbox then though label has space to display more than 13 characters it will display only 13 characters(including dots).
   Does anybody has solution on that ?? I also cannot increase width or height of label to accomodate more characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you could set the `AutoEllipsis` property to true and don't worry about the length of the text.

**Edited to Add**: *as per comments*

If you're using [RadLabel](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/panels-and-labels-label-overview.html) from Telerik then you need to dig a little more:

```
RadLabel.LabelElement.LabelText.AutoEllipsis
```

Nothing that 5 minutes looking through the documentation doens't solve

Comment: This doesn't require Visual Studio 2010. It will work in the older versions, too.

Comment: yep... I forgot about it... it has beena long while since i used WinForms in VS2008.. :-P

Comment: I am using radlabel ... it does not have AutoEllipsis property.

Comment: RadLabel does have AutoEllipsis

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your reply.. But when I go in   RadLabel.LabelElement.LabelText.AutoEllipsis it's property was already set(AutoEllipsis = true) but still it is not working.No dots are displayed.

Comment: Wow, so a `RadLabel` is one that allows you to create **completely unreadable** user interfaces? Looking at the sample form in the documentation you linked, the shadows/embossing on that text makes it so blurry that it makes my eyes hurt. I can't imagine what would *possibly* be the point of this. Glad to see it's not lacking in obvious features, though...

Comment: Unfortunately I don't use RadLabel to see what exactly is the problem.. I just looked at the docs.

Answer (score 4):

Set the [**`AutoEllipsis`** property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.autoellipsis.aspx) of your `Label` control to true. You can do this either in the designer, or through code:

```
myLabel.AutoEllipsis = true;
```

That will cause the ellipsis character (...) to be automatically appended to the text if it overflows the space available in the label. You won't have to manage this yourself in code at all.

This property is available as far back as .NET 3.0.

Comment: I am using radlabel ... it does not have AutoEllipsis property

Comment: @Sachin: I've never heard of a "radlabel". I assume it's some kind of custom label control. What does it provide that the standard `Label` control doesn't? Why not switch to one that provides the functionality you need? This is available right out-of-the-box; makes those third-party controls look pretty pointless. Omitting important details like that from your question makes it very difficult to get the right answer.

Comment: Ok... Radcontorls are third-party contorls and radlabel is one of the control. I can move to noraml window label for my above problem . I checked with windows label by seting its AutoEllipssi property to true and it's working as I need. But there is another problem if I use winodw label then I need rounded corners for the same. Do you have any soluttion for this ??

Comment: I am getting rounded corners on radlabel.

Comment: @Sachin: How does a label have rounded corners? I'm not sure how it has any corners at all. Set the background color to be the same as your form.

Comment: It does not have naturally. But as per our client requirement he needs one with round corners....

Comment: @Sachin: No, there's no rounded corners on the built-in label control. I still don't know what rounded corners even look like on a label. It's not like a label on a piece of paper; the background of the form is supposed to show through. There shouldn't be any corners at all.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use Textbox.MaxLength property which only allows the user to enter the maximum number of characters you set the value to.

Comment: No user can enter any number of characters in textbox. But while dispalying them in label it is showing as per above condition.

Comment: He does, but he also states that he enters the text into a Textbox.  Maybe i've mis-interpreted the question.

Comment: Yes text is entered in textbox and whatever value user enters it is taken by label.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the label's [**`AutoEllipsis`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.autoellipsis%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property to `true` and let it figure this out for itself.

> Gets or sets a value indicating
>   whether the ellipsis character (...)
>   appears at the right edge of the
>   Label, denoting that the Label text
>   extends beyond the specified length of
>   the Label.

Comment: may be this could have worked if I was using normal winform label but I am working on radlabel.Radlabel has no such property.